# process.env.token not working on discord bot startup

Tags: github, heroku, discord.js

I am trying to make my discord bot stay online 24/7 using Heroku and Github. but whenever I try to run my code I get this error.

```
2022-01-01T03:56:43.950025+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2022-01-01T03:56:43.950043+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2022-01-01T03:56:43.950043+00:00 app[Worker.1]:           ^^^
2022-01-01T03:56:43.950044+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2022-01-01T03:56:43.950044+00:00 app[Worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

There is two spots where I put my token, and I use process.env.token in those slots.
First one is my index.js file

```
(async () => {
    for (file of functions) {
        require(`./src/functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, ".src/events");
    client.handleCommands(commandFolders, "./src/commands");
    client.login(process.env.token);
})();
```

second is my handlecommands.js file

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async(commandFolders, path) => {
        client.commandArray = [];
        for (folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                // Set a new item in the Collection
                // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }
        const rest = new REST({
             version: '9' 
        }).setToken(process.env.token);
```

How can I fix this?
(Quick Disclaimer, I do not have a .env file but I do have a procfile telling Heroku what to do)
`Worker: node index.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Heroku App is using a outdated / older version of Node.js, where  `??=` isn't available. Since you can't directly update the Node.js version for your Heroku app, you can set the version you need in your `package.json`.

Simply add the following lines after the, e.g. `"description"`, object:

```json
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x" (or another version, depending on which one you need)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know this is all I had to do :D

Comment: Glad I could help ^^